# How to open ObjectBox in Flutter once and access across several pages

Tags: flutter, objectbox

In Flutter, I am attempting to open an ObjectBox database in a class, create a single instance of the 'store' and use it across several pages by calling a method in that class as necessary.

I have adopted this to the "Notes" example (given in official documentation) as follows. My intention is to keep the class OpenDB in a separate file and import it to other files that need to fetch/store user-data;

```
class OpenDB {
   OpenDB();
  
  static late Store obStore;
  
  static void createStore() {
     openStore().then((Store store) {
     obStore = store;
     });
  }
  
  static Store getStore() {
   return obStore;
  }
}
```

Then, I have modified the initState() in the original example code as follows;

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _noteInputController = TextEditingController();
  final _listController = StreamController<List<Note>>(sync: true);
  late final ViewModel _vm;
  late final Store _store;

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();

  OpenDB.createStore();        // will be called only once, perhaps in the main.dart
  _store = OpenDB.getStore();  // will be called in several pages as needed

  _vm = ViewModel(_store);

  _listController.addStream(_vm.queryStream.map((q) => q.find()));

}
// ............ code continues from the original example as it is.........
```

When I attempt to run this, it gives a runtime error: -

> The following LateError was thrown building Builder:

> LateInitializationError: Field 'obStore' has not been initialized.

What am I missing here?
Any advice is highly appreciated please. Thank you

Comment: I've started working on an updated example that initializes the Store only once for the whole app. See https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/pull/316

Comment: Uwe - 
many thanks for the lead; I tried it OK.  Must check how this could be adopted to: - getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((dir) { . . . . . route for creating a store with a name of our choice.

Answer (score 0):

inside initState()  copy  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

Example 
@override 
void initState() {
super.initState();
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
OpenDB.createStore();
.
.
.